# Cordova get screen width and height on 'device ready' event

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have a problem to get screen width and height in my Cordova app. I need those values right after the app starts. Right now I'm trying something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    'use strict';

     var canvas = document.querySelector('#myApp'),
         ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
         appSize = {
             w: window.innerWidth,
             h: window.innerHeight
         };

     canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
     canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

     (code code code code)

}, flase)
```

The problem is that canvas gets 0px width and 0px height. One thing worth mentioning is that when I set those values later (for example after 'touchstart' event) everything works.

Anybody knows a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use jquery function. And should use document.ready instead of deviceready. May be your deviceready running  before page load. There is very little difference of timing between deviceready and document.ready.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var height = $(window).height(); 
var width = $(window).width(); 
// do something
});
```

Comment: Ok, now I understand. The window object is not ready at that moment. Strange, Cordova documentation is recommending deviceready. BTW using jQuery only for $(document).ready is really bad idea.

Comment: jquery is not only for document.ready. You have to use jquery further in your cordova app if you want to write less code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree with that :)