# Get device height in cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am trying to find device's height in Cordova?

```
pChart.chartHeight = 100;
```

What can I write instead of `100`? `100` should be the device's height.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086271/cordova-get-screen-width-and-height-on-device-ready-event

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan window.innerWidth doesnt work

Comment: You're reading the question, check the answer instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38086846/519413

Answer (score 2):

From `window.screen` you can obtain its width and height properties, but you should also add the pixel densities since it may change on orientation or among different devices. Try this:

```
var physicalScreenHeight = window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio;

productionChart.chartHeight = physicalScreenHeight;
```

And have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html) in case you have more doubts.

Answer (score 1):

use [.resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  alert($(window).height() + $(window).width);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var w = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;

var h = window.innerHeight
|| document.documentElement.clientHeight
|| document.body.clientHeight;

alert(w +" - "+h);
```

Comment: does not work window.innerWidth when rotate thre screen

Comment: other conditions should work. try document.documentElement.clientHeight

Comment: I need orientation lanscape